# how to pass values from one to page to another one in pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

now I have two views

```
@view_config(route_name='upload',render='foo.mako')
    if 'upload.submitted' in request.params:
        input_file = request.POST['upload'].file
        while 1:
            data = imput_file.readline().strip()
            if no data:
               break
            data_list = data.split(',')
            email = data_list[0]
            password = data_list[1]

        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('manage')

    return {}

@view_config(route_name='manage',render='bar.mako')
    return {}
```

how can I pass the data from view "upload" to "mamage"

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is making little sense. You want to redirect to a second view (which is a GET request). And therefore you can pass only "simple" data using URL parameters. Passing an uploaded file through GET is not possible. You must store the uploaded data somewhere and pass the information around using a reference. Another option is to stick relevant information inside a session (see pyramid.session documentation) in order make the information "survive" across requests.